# Partially making tooltip text bold

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I'm trying to make the first line of text from my tool tip to be bold.
The code below is what I currently have and it doesn't work.

```
  tooltip.html("<b>" + smartData[yearSlider][d3.select(this).attr("country")]["country"] + "</b> <br>" +
  "Total CO2 Emission excluding LULUCF" + "<br>" + 
  smartData[yearSlider][d3.select(this).attr("country")]["totalghgexlulucf"] + 
  "<br>" + "Total CO2 Emission including LULUCF" + "<br>" +
  smartData[yearSlider][d3.select(this).attr("country")]["totalghginclulucf"] +
  "<br>")
```

The screenshot below is the result of the code above (some CSS was used to style the tooltip, etc.)

[Result of tooltip code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4gCi.png)

Can anyone help me with this?
If you need more code to help me with this problem, I'm more than happy to share it with you! :)

Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your <b> tag does not have the closing one </b>

Comment: Did you set `data-html="true"` in your HTML item or via your JS tooltip initialization?

Comment: Can you please also provide the code you're using to create the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can solve this by using a span with a class and style the class in your css file:

```
tooltip.html("<span class='tooltip-text-bold'>" + smartData[yearSlider][d3.select(this).attr("country")]["country"] + "</span> <br>" +
  "Total CO2 Emission excluding LULUCF" + "<br>" + 
  smartData[yearSlider][d3.select(this).attr("country")]["totalghgexlulucf"] + 
  "<br>" + "Total CO2 Emission including LULUCF" + "<br>" +
  smartData[yearSlider][d3.select(this).attr("country")]["totalghginclulucf"] +
  "<br>")
```

then you style in css using:

```
.tooltip-text-bold{
    font-weight: 700;
}
```